# Java timer issue with starting application

Tags: java, import, timer

very new to java so please explain at a basic level. Attempting to make a snake game. In the process of typing up the code for the games background. Having an issue with the timer. The lines with issues marked with ***

```
 package snake;

 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.Toolkit;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

  import javax.swing.JFrame;


 public class Snake implements ActionListener {

         public JFrame jframe;
         public RenderPanel renderPanel;    
         public static Snake snake;


         public Snake() {
             Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
             jframe = new JFrame("Snake");
             jframe.setVisible(true);
             jframe.setSize(800, 700);
             jframe.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - jframe.getWidth() / 2, dim.height / 2 - jframe.getHeight() / 2);
             jframe.add(renderPanel = new RenderPanel());
             jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


         }

     public static void main (String []args) {
          snake = new Snake();
      }

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
          renderPanel.repaint();

      }
```

Comment: Nice marking of the problematic areas, but you missed to tell us, what the problem is.

Comment: Can you explain to us what it is exactly that's causing 'issues'. Kudos on the nice markup on your first post!

Comment: The first error is showing me "The constructor Timer(int, Snake) is undefined"

Comment: The second is "The method start() is undefined for the type Timer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot initialize a Timer with a int and a Snake object. That is not supported by the Timer class. Have a look at the [Java Api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html). The Constructor Summary Shows you, which Constructors exist for the Timer class.

When you want to do something after a defined time do the following:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new ReceiverTask(), 1000);
```

The 1000 is the delay in milliseconds untill the run method of the ReceiverTask will be called.

ReceiverTask should be a class extending TimeTask. For example:

```
class ReceiverTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        //update your Background her
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sending the attachment, most appreciated. My intention is for the background to change color. But at this point in time, without having the timer start the application will not run

Comment: At which time? After a few mili seconds?

Comment: At this point it wont open at all. But I believe that issue is coming from my line 32   *** snake = new Snake(); ***    where i'm returning a small arrow saying the method start is undefined for the type Timer

Comment: That line should work. Can you please update the Code in your question?

Comment: I have updated it. The timer issue still remains where outlined by the *** completely unsure why

Comment: Because Timer has no function start(). That is why I asked, what you want to do with the timer.

Comment: Ah, I'm following you. I was just under the assumption that the timer is needed to begin the application

Comment: Ive ran the application without any timer coding and it opens fine. I'm wanting to get the background color to change. Hence the use of the timer